# Error while installing SUITECRM with Xammp on ubuntu

Tags: suitecrm

While installing suitecrm‌‌ I faced an error. mysql and Apache server is running on xammp. However when I try installing suitecrm it gives an error.‌ I‌ have pasted the unzipped folder of SuiteCRM in htdocs directory of Xammp.
Below is the error:

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: fwrite(): Argument #1 ($stream) must be of type resource, bool given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/suitecrm/install/install_utils.php:732 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/suitecrm/install/install_utils.php(732): fwrite(false, '\n2023-09-21 14:...') #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/suitecrm/install/install_utils.php(64): installLog('installerHook: ...') #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/suitecrm/install.php(827): installerHook('pre_installFile...', Array) #3 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/suitecrm/install/install_utils.php on line 732

Comment: What PHP, MySQL and SuiteCRM versions are you using?

Comment: I am using suitecrm version 7.14.0, and php mysql are installed with xammp. probably php 8.2.10 which is supported by suitecrm 7.14.0. apache2 and mysql 8.0.34. all of thess version are supported by suitecrm 7.14.0 as it is written in the compatibility matrix. Could you provide me with ur whatsapp or email so that I can contact you easily. I know you know a lot regarding suitecrm installation

Comment: Please help me in this regard.‌ I‌ am really struck. I have been trying so hard and since a lot of time.‌ I started working on it in the first week of my internship and today the third week has begun.